# Refreshing grids in different components flex 4.5

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have one main xml file wich contains 2 components.
Component 1 is an upload component component 2 is a grid with a list.
Both are in the same viewstate but i want component 2 to update when i uploaded a file in component 1.

So my question is: How can i send a trigger to component 2 from component 1 so it knows the grid has to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communication between components, use events.

For instance inside component 1 dispatch a "complete" event whenever the upload is finished:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
```

Now listen for this event and tell component 2 what to do. Do something like this in your main class:

```
component1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleUploadComplete);

private function handleUploadComplete(event:Event):void {
    component2.updateGrid();
}
```

---

If you want MXML support for that, add the following metadata to component 1:

```
[Event(name="complete", type="flash.events.Event")]
```

You can then listen for the event like this and FlashBuilder will suggest the event handler:

```
<Component1 complete="handleUploadComplete()" />
```

Comment: Now i get this error: Cannot resolve attribute 'complete' for component type Components.Mp3up.mxml

Comment: Have you recompiled that class with the additional metadata as I described? If it's an mxml file it should be inside an `<fx:Metadata>` tag.

Comment: yes but i made a typo :D i tend to type over things instead of copy pasting so i remember them better afterwards :) bedankt!